# PHP shell_exec() Behaves Differently Than Terminal Command Line MacOS

Tags: php, bash, macos, terminal, scanline

Scanline is a simple command line utility used for scanning documents from a twain scanner.  http://blog.scottkleper.com/scanline-command-line-scanner-for-mac/

I am trying to use Scanline through a PHP script using shell_exec(); the same way that I would use it directly from the terminal in MacOS.

When I run Scanline directly from the command line, it detects all the attached scanners and prints them out `./scanline -list`

When I run Scanline using shell_exec(), it does not detect any devices.

So far, I have changed the apache user to my local user, and have added the local user to the sudoers file.  If I run 'whoami' in shell_exec() it is the same result as if I run it in command line.

I have printed the environment using `printenv` in command line, and have setup all of the same variables in my php script before executing shell_exec() using putenv();  If I run shell_exec('printenv 2>&1'), it is the exact same environment as when I run printenv in command line.

All the permissions are correct and allow access, and scanline runs when executed through shell_exec() without error (I checked apache's error logs, as well as put a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the top of the PHP file to printout any issues along the way).  The only difference in how the program is executed is that in command line the devices are detected, and run through shell_exec(), no devices are found.

Any ideas as to what else I could be missing between command line and using shell_exec() ?

I also tried using system(), exec(), and shell_exec() interchangeably with the same result.

Comment: does it run and outputs nothing, or not run and you see nothing in the output ?  same symptom, different cause.

Comment: Make sure you execute scanline with the full path. i.e. /fullpath/scanline. Also check your error logs for an indication of whats going on.

Comment: No, I get an output when I put the full path to scanline & 2>&1 at the end of the command.  It's just that when shell_exec() runs the command, the program doesn't find any devices attached to the system, but when run in command line then it does.

Comment: There's a handful of similar questions on here, and they never seem to get answered...  It's pretty clunky, but a quick solution that I ended up using was to use shell_exec() to execute an applescript that tells terminal to run the scanline command.  Using applescript to run the command in terminal behaves exactly the same as if I were to run the command in terminal directly, the only catch is that shell_exec() needs to use `open` to run the applescript, not `osascript`.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Also to make it slightly less of a pain, you can hide the applescript by adding this to the info.plist file (When saved as an app) `<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>`
`<string>1</string>`